# How do I add my Birthday in Ubuntu 16.04 Calendar App

Tags: 16.04, calendar

I want to add my Family member's birthday in Calendar app which is inbuild in Ubuntu 16.04. When I try it, there is a option to add event only to Personal not birthday. Please guide to solve it.

[image: Add Event]

When I try to add Birthday

[image: Add birthday]

**There is no way to check birthday & anniversaries**.

So I decide to go to Calendar Setting in menu

[image]

There is no way to add Birthday.

Comment: You may need to add contacts to use it.

Comment: Like all things gnome, gnome did not decide that you may use this feature in this way. You should not be doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Birthdays & Anniversaries" agenda is automatically filled when you add contacts. To do that, use the Contacts application.

Comment: yayy.. that's annoying :3

Answer (score 0):

gnome-contacts is a separate program that must be installed for this answer to work.  Look at a screenshot of gnome-contacts to see if that program suits you.

It may be simpler and less cluttered to just use the gnome-calendar:

Manage Calendars --> Add Calendar

That will result in a unified calendar, which is what you're after.  gnome-calendar "Edit Details" when creating or modifying an entry allows it to be set as a recurring annual event.